# is it safe to pass the user to view in laravel?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

Is it? I mean if you get the user with `$user = Auth::user();` and then send it to the view with `return view ('somepage')->with('user',$user);` the browser will get all user data in the view (uername, password, user_id etc..). I know you can then show what you like example `{{$user->username}}` but the point is, is the rest of the data somehow accessible to an 'hacker', 'script kiddie' or the likes?

Answer (score 1):

`Auth::user()` is accesible from all views anyway.

Browser will not get all info like `password`, `user_id` etc. Browser gets only HTML generated by Blade template engine and it contains only things you want to share.

For example, you'll do `{{ Auth::user()->username }}`, browser will get `username`, but nothing else.

Comment: No? If I dd($user) in the controller before passing it to the view I get everything. And also if I print_r($user); in the view I get the whole thing.

Comment: `dd()` shows you contents of variables. collections etc. Of course it will display everything. In real app you will never use `dd()` or `var_dump()` or something similar.

Comment: Yes what I mean is, is there a way to a third party to intercept the collection being sent to the view and display it like you would with a var_dump or similar?

Comment: No, there is no way for any browser or JS code to get password from `Auth::user()`, for example. That's server side thing. Blade and PHP uses a lot of stuff for, basically, genereate HTML.

Comment: if you want something to be hiddin in the auth::user you can do that in the model i guess using the $hidden [ 'password','phone']